# cakephp change url to new url

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the CakePHP program ( version 2.1.3) what is running already ( on Centos 6.x and Apache ).

Now I want to change url from: `http://domain.com/frontend/login`

to new url like: `http://domain.com/user-login.html`

I changed routes.php like below:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug.html', 
    array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'login'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug')
    )
);
```

and added the following code in my login.ctp :

```
<?php 
 echo $html->link('user login', 
        array(  
            'controller' => 'frontend',    
            'action' => 'login',    
            'slug' => Inflector::slug('user login'))); 
?>
```

It success and now I can access with new URL: `http://domain.com/user-login.html`

But I also still can access with old url: `http://domain.com/frontend/login`

I only want to access new URL, and remove old URL.

How I can do? please guide me the details.

Thank.

Comment: frontend is controller and login is function, If you write controller and action both in url then it is accessible, if user open this then you need to redirect user to second url or you need to write code .httaccess file

Comment: I dont know how to change .htaccess file. Can you tell me how to config .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ptica's answer is a good one, but if you want something that doesn't disable all of CakePHP's default routes then I'd add redirect rules to the .htaccess file:-

```
Redirect 301 /frontend/login /user-login.html
```

.htaccess is a better place to put your redirects than in the routes file as it will be more efficient. It would probably be a good idea to put a comment about this in the routes file for future reference though; otherwise you or someone else will look at the project one day and be confused at what is redirecting!

There shouldn't really be an issue with leaving the route as is though as long as you:-

- always use Cake's Router/HtmlHelper to generate links so that the correct alias is used
- include a [canonical url](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on the page so that search engines use the correct url

That way the app should never reference `/frontend/login`.

Comment: I tried to setup like your code in .htaccess file ( in root folder, the same with app folder )
I can not open link:  http://domain.com/user-login.html
My expectation: Open link : http://domain.com/user-login.html
remove old link: http://domain.com/frontend/login

I tried to config: 
RewriteRule  ^user-login.html  /frontend/login/
But it still not success

Comment: @haicnpmk44 you need to open a new StackOverflow question for this. Make sure you show your .htaccess code in the question. There are lots of .htaccess experts on this site. :-)

Answer (score 1):

at the bottom of your `routes.php` file there is this statement:

`/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';`

just comment out the `require` line and you should be all set